# BizTalk Server Migration to 2016

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

> Uncaught exception (see the 'inner exception' below) has suspended an instance of service 'CSC.Integration.Orchestrations.LegacyBizTalkProcess(71c7729e-22ac-be38-00c0-0b11beaba439)'.
>   The service instance will remain suspended until administratively resumed or terminated. 
>   If resumed the instance will continue from its last persisted state and may re-throw the same unexpected exception.
>   InstanceId: 296a4475-58f6-4fa4-8b90-65fe752e9872
>   Shape name: e_Logging
>   ShapeId: 919d78da-57e8-4ae1-bd2f-39859310c6de
>   Exception thrown from: segment 1, progress 20
>   Inner exception: The type initializer for 'CSC.AppBlocks.Logging.Logger' threw an exception.
>
> Exception type: TypeInitializationException
>   Source: CSC.AppBlocks.Logging
>   Target Site: Void Write(CSC.AppBlocks.Logging.Category, System.String, System.String)
>   The following is a stack trace that identifies the location where the exception occured
>
> at CSC.AppBlocks.Logging.Logger.Write(Category category, String message, String title)
>      at CSC

We are working on BizTalk migration to 2016 and in testing the application we are getting above error and we updated all Gacs and for this receive location we are using MSMQ adapter. But it is working in BizTalk server 2010.

Comment: So, first question...do you really need the "Logger"?  99.9%...no, even though you think you do.  My solution would be to remove any custom logging and use the Windows Event Log which has always worked for me.

Comment: need to review the code and check what its doing

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure the DLL that contains the namespace CSC.AppBlocks.Logging is GAC'd?
2. Are there other DLLs that CSC.AppBlocks.Logging depends on that may not be GAC'd?
3. Did you restart the host instance after GAC'ing the DLL?
4. Is your DLL 32-bit only? If so, make sure you change your host instance settings to only run as a 32-bit process.
5. Is there an inner exception reported in any of the messages? Perhaps in the Event Viewer?